# updating database through data which sent in url

Tags: php, get

trying to update database through data which is enter in url but it doesn't give any result
i got data from form which is on same page through post
and sending this data through url as

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://localhost/service/service.php?action=update_details&name1='.$name1.'&lname1='.$lname1.'&email1='.$email1.'&username1='.$username1.'&password1='.$password1.'&gender1='.$gender1.'&mobile1='.$mobile1.'&address1='.$address1.'id1='.$id1.");
```

now that data is fetched through get method on another file and send to function which updates database

```
 if($tag == 'update_details')
{    
    $id = $_GET['id1'];
    $name=($_GET['name1']);     
    $lname=($_GET['lname1']);
    $email=($_GET['email1']);   
    $username=($_GET['username1']);   
    $password=($_GET['password1']); 
    $gender=($_GET['gender1']);
    $mobile=($_GET['mobile1']);
    $address=($_GET['address1']);

    //exit (json_encode($email));
    if ($db ->updateUser($id,$name,$lname,$email,$username,$password,$gender,$mobile,$address)) 
    {
        //  $app_info = "success";
            exit (json_encode("success"));
    }else
    {
        $error="not done";  
         exit (json_encode($error));

    } 

}
```

and function is on another file where updating code present but it gives me error as not done

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: sorry i write wrong statement it gives me message as not done

Comment: can you please give us $db->updateUser() methods code and you tables screenshot ?

Comment: can i email you the code

Comment: First of all - term on the error_reporting within your dev site. This will help  you debug your code. You have the string in the get_file_contents is invalid - check the single/double quotes.

Comment: i did changes as you suggested now code runs well but new values are not shown in data base

Comment: You need to post your database image here @SACHINGAJBHIYE :)

Comment: i did some changes in my code as far as result concerned it just fine some silly mistakes from me but got idea thanks for ur help